# refresh page using javascript (location.reload()) not working on android 2.3.x

Tags: javascript, android, refresh

Does anyone encountered this? Anyone has a solution?

I'm trying to implement "logoff" feature in my mobile app, by removing the user's cookies and refresh the page using

```
location.reload();
```

But it's not working on android 2.3.x..

Help would me much appreciated!
Thanks..

Doron

Comment: `location.href = location.href;`

Comment: Tried.. didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

location.reload(true); 
This one worked for me last time. 
If still not please do reply me. 
also you might have done something like this 
.setAppCacheEnabled(true); 
.setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);  
.setCacheMode(1);